# Need to unzip a file, where can I save it in JSF web application?

Tags: jsf

My task right now is to get a *.xlsx file from my application resources, edit some values in it, and with edited values let user download the file.

As for now I found out, that what I need to do is:

- get a file from my resource
- unzip it, since *.xlsx files are nothing more than just zipped together few xml files holding data
- edit values in a some files
- pack it all together
- spit it out for user to download

The only step on the road that I don't get, is where I should unzip the file.

Maybe someone can give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of OS-managed "temporary file" facility as available by [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)). The servletcontainer-managed destination for temporary folder is available as application scoped attribute with [`ServletContext.TEMPDIR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR) as key.

```
File tempDir = (File) externalContext.getApplicationMap().get(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix-", ".suffix", tempDir);
// Write to it.
```